# Login Authentication through HtmlUnit Web Client

Tags: java, httpclient, webclient, htmlunit, urlconnection

I want to post a data using webclient but i have problem on submit button because i am not getting submit button object in page source.so how can i use this button in webclient.this is the source code which is creates button in web.

```
<a class="btn-cta btn-type1 _submit" onclick="hs.throbberMgrObj.add('._submit'); $('#member').submit();" href="#">
```

this is the HtmlUnit WebClient code which i am using-

```
HtmlHiddenInput submitButton = null;
            try {
                submitButton = forms.get(0).getInputByName("form_submit");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            HtmlTextInput usernameInput = form.getInputByName("");
            HtmlPasswordInput passInput = form.getInputByName("");
            usernameInput.setValueAttribute();
            passInput.setValueAttribute();
            HtmlPage pageAfterLogin = (HtmlPage) submitButton.click();
```

Note: I have already try HttpClient and urlConnection but it is not provide proper solution.

Thanks In Advanced.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573558/htmlunit-how-to-post-form-without-clicking-submit-button

Comment: I don't find button name from web page.so how to get button object or any other alternate for this.

Comment: Check second answer. It's suggested to create button manually and insert it to form. May be it works.