# Posting data using web client

Tags: java, httpclient, webclient, httpurlconnection

I am creating a submit button using a web client, but it's not working.

This is the code, which I am using:

```
 HtmlElement button = firstPage.createElement("button");
 button.setAttribute("type", "submit");
 button.setAttribute("name", "submit");
 form.appendChild(button);
 System.out.println(form.asXml());
 HtmlPage pageAfterLogin = button.click();
```

Comment: In what way is it - arghh! - not working?

Comment: I want to post a data using webclient but i have problem on submit button because i am not getting submit button object in page source.so that i am creating own button using this code.

Comment: what is the librairy used?... htmlUnit? Can we see the corresponding HTML?

Comment: Never name a form element "submit". It can "overwrite" the `submit()` method of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple question, Do you have HTML FORM tag included in the page?
Also see below link, not sure if it helps you

[HtmlUnit, how to post form without clicking submit button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573558/htmlunit-how-to-post-form-without-clicking-submit-button)